# I want to below the image when i click on amount the amount will automatically come on my edit text amount is a textview

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wQMm.jpg)
what i have to use to when the user click on amount value the amount value automatically come in edit text

Comment: Also you need to formulate your question better, I had some confusion reading your question and I imagine some do, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be using an `onClickListener` on each value button to get the clicked event and the value of that specific button.

After that you can update your `amount` variable accordingly, then show it onto the UI by using `textField.setText()`

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your Buttons or TextViews are similar, you can put them inside an array and call forEach{ ... } method.

Inside that method you set an onClickListener where you get the clicked item's text and set your EditText's text.

it may be something like :

```
val button_list = listOf(
        button_300, 
        button_1000, 
        button_1500, 
        ..., 
        button_50000
)
button_list.forEach{ button ->
    button.setOnClickListener{
        your_editText.setText(button.getText().toString())
    }
}
```